# Plugin backstretch.js diminui o tamanho do background do site

Tags: jquery

Galera, estou tendo dificuldades em ajustar um erro que esta dando em tema do Wordpress.
O plugin **backstretch** redimensiona o background do site deixando a imagem distorcida, já procurei diversas soluções mas nenhuma resolveu, também já tentei manipular os dados do CSS de inúmeras formas e nada...

Vou colocar umas imagens, se algum puder me ajudar ficarei grato! =D
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**Uma das soluções que tentei via CSS (background-size: cover;)**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
**O código do danado como está no CSS...**

Alguém puder me dar uma luz de como resolver isso! Vlw...